# where is the Azure runtime Integration has to be installed?

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am trying to pull the data from the on premise oracle database to the azure blob storage using azure data factory. When I went through the documentation it suggested to install the self hosted integration runtime in a windows machine.

So my question is where we need to install this runtime exactly. Do we have to create a separate VM for this as I can't install anything in the oracle hosted machine? If yes then how will the newly created VM will have access to connect with the oracle database.

Please let me know if some more clarity is required. I am new to this technology so please suggest me any other measure that I can go through to pull the data from on premise oracle database to azure blob storage.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Self-hosted Integration Runtime should be installed on one of the machines in **your local network**, near to the database. Via the network, the app should be able to connect to your Oracle database like any other client application.
The following picture explains it pretty well:

[image]
Probably a lot of your questions raised because you were thinking about VM in Azure, weren't you?